# filtering a weird text file in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a text file in which each ID line starts with `>` and the next line(s) are the a sequence of characters. And the next line after the sequence of characters would be an other ID line starting with `>`. but in some of them, instead of sequence I have `“Sequence unavailable”`. The sequence after the ID line can be one or more lines.
like this example:

```
>ENSG00000173153|ENST00000000442|64073050;64074640|64073208;64074651
AAGCAGCCGGCGGCGCCGCCGAGTGAGGGGACGCGGCGCGGTGGGGCGGCGCGGCCCGAGGAGGCGGCGGAGGAGGGGCCGCCCGCGGCCCCCGGCTCACTCCGGCACTCCGGGCCGCTC
>ENSG00000004139|ENST00000003834
Sequence unavailable
```

I want to filter out those IDs with `“Sequence unavailable”`. The output should look like this:

output:

```
>ENSG00000173153|ENST00000000442|64073050;64074640|64073208;64074651
AAGCAGCCGGCGGCGCCGCCGAGTGAGGGGACGCGGCGCGGTGGGGCGGCGCGGCCCGAGGAGGCGGCGGAGGAGGGGCCGCCCGCGGCCCCCGGCTCACTCCGGCACTCCGGGCCGCTC
```

do you know how to do that in python?

Comment: Use a regular expression with `re.sub()`, eg [`^>.+[\r\n]^Sequence unavailable$`](https://regex101.com/r/vkYFd0/1) and the `multiline` modifier.

Comment: Clearly, this if FASTA format, but where did these "Sequence unavailable" lines come from? Maybe you should tackle the issue at the source. Also consider using `BioPython`

Comment: @Chris_Rands They probably come from Ensembl Biomart.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Really thanks? I'm surprised Ensembl return such a format, will likely trip up many FASTA parsers

Comment: @Chris_Rands Oh I know. It’s very annoying that such sequence records even exist. I’ve tried finding out but even though I got a response from their team I’m still not convinced that this isn’t simply a Biomart bug.

Comment: Not python and not free, but the commercial tool [SeqNinja](https://www.dnastar.com/t-seqninja.aspx) from DNASTAR makes it really easy to filter FASTA files and other sequence formats. In upcoming release 15.0, this could be accomplished with the single command `out.fasta = sample( in.fasta, startsWith!='Sequence' )`. In addition to the UI, there's a command-shell that accepts command-line arguments. Note: I work for DNASTAR, and worked on this product.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike the other answers, I’d strongly recommand against parsing the FASTA format manually. It’s not too hard but there *are* pitfalls, and it’s completely unnecessary since efficient, well-tested implementations exist:

Use [`Bio.SeqIO`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) from BioPython; for example:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fasta'):
    if record.seq != 'Sequenceunavailable':
        SeqIO.write(record, outfile, 'fasta')
```

Note the missing space in `'Sequenceunavailable'`: reading the sequences in FASTA format will omit spaces.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.split('>')
    result = ['>{}'.format(item) for item in data if item and 'Sequence unavailable' not in item]
    f.seek(0)
    for line in result:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Why do you test for `if item`? `item` will never be `None` or empty, and OP hasn’t specified what to do with empty items anyway. But what’s more, using `in` here instead of equality is *much* less efficient because the sequences can be quite long.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    filename = open('text.txt', 'rU').readlines()
    filterFile(filename)

def filterFile(SequenceFile):
    outfile = open('outfile', 'w')
    for line in SequenceFile:
         if line.startswith('>'):
            sequence = line.next()
            if sequence.startswith('Sequence unavailable'):
            //nothing should happen I suppose? 
            else: 
            outfile.write(line + "\n" + sequence + "\n")

main()
```

I unfortunately can't test this code right now but I made this out of the top of my head! Please test it and let me know what the outcome is so I can adjust the code :-)

Answer (score -2):

So I don't exactly know how large these files will get, just in case, I'm doing it without mapping the file in memory:

```
with open(filename) as fh:
    with open(filename+'.new', 'w+') as fh_new:
        for idline, geneseq in zip(*[iter(fh)] * 2):
            if geneseq.strip() != 'Sequence unavailable':
                fh_new.write(idline)
                fh_new.write(geneseq)
```

It works by creating a new file, then the zip thing is some magic to read the 2 lines of the file, the `idline` will be the first part and the `geneseq` the second part.

This solution should be relatively cheap in computer power but will create an extra output file.

Comment: This will fail if a FASTA record has more than one line, which is frequent in FASTA files.

Comment: didn't know the file format. As the format is described in the original question it would work. If what you say is true, this answer would indeed be flawed.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good example + definition of the format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format